# Why is the button not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The "go button" is not working as it should. When clicked it should hide the subviews. Here's the ViewController. I tried placing the final function in various places.

```
class timeViewController: UIViewController {


var score = 0
var buttonState: Int = 0;
var gameOver = UIView()

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

  if(displayTime.text != stoptimer.text){

        var gameOver = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        gameOver.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        //gameOver.opaque = false
        self.view.addSubview(gameOver)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations:{
            gameOver.frame.size = CGSizeMake(667, 667)
        })

        let gobutton = UIButton()
        let image = "button.png"
        gobutton.setImage(UIImage(named: image), forState: .Normal)
        gobutton.frame = CGRectMake(135, 300, 95, 95)
        gobutton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(gobutton)

        func pressed(sender: UIButton!){
             gameOver.removeFromSuperview()
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're re-declaring gameOver inside the if statement. Just remove var. Check this code out:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var gameOver: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(displayTime.text != stoptimer.text){

        gameOver = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0))
        gameOver.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
        //gameOver.opaque = false
        self.view.addSubview(gameOver)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0, animations:{
            self.gameOver.frame.size = CGSizeMake(667, 667)
        })

        let gobutton = UIButton()
        let image = "button.png"
        gobutton.setImage(UIImage(named: image), forState: .Normal)
        gobutton.frame = CGRectMake(135, 300, 95, 95)
        gobutton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(gobutton)

    }
}

func pressed(sender: UIButton!){
    self.gameOver.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing your "GaneOver" view change to this code:

```
gameOver.removeFromSuperview()
```

And I hope you are writing "func pressed" outside of viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear

Comment: @tanman Please make sure that you have define `var gameOver: UIView!` globally

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make `gameOver` a global variable by declaring it outside  function and then do what you did like this:

```
class myClass {
    var gameOver = UIView()

    func myFunction() {/*edit everything including gameOverView's properties*/}
    func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        gameOver.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Also make sure to write functions outside other functions like `viewDidLoad` but inside your class as it looks like you created that function inside another one. However you can call a function from within another one using something like `myFunction()` as separate line as is.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Weird. What about `subView` or `view`?

Comment: I changed that line of code to `gameOver.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: Since that apparently occurs with the other answer as well I don't believe that error has something to do with our code solutions. Also, have you moved the function?

Comment: I moved the function, and I got rid of the SIGABRT error, but I'm getting another error. http://puu.sh/itcrO/4449b74a8d.png

Comment: What does the console say about it?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: Alright, so `gameOver` appears to be nil. How did you declare it?

Comment: `var gameOver: UIView!`

Comment: Ok, make it the way I did: `var gameOver = UIView()`. Then it won't be nil anymore and your app should not crash.

Comment: But it does not crash anymore right? Now that is one step closer. Next up: Edit its properties in the `viewDidLoad` or somewhere that gets called before the `gameOver`View is presented.

Comment: Well, whichever you want to edit. Also make sure to add all the labels etc. that you want to appear on the view to it using `gameOver.addSubview(myLabel)`

Comment: Is there a reason why when the button is clicked, nothing happens?

Comment: I could only tell from your code. Update your question and show your current code, I'll be able to help.

Comment: Ok, you should really go and learn the very basics of Swift and basically any other programming language. For now: you have to put everything into functions (aka methods). The only thing not in functions are declarations for global variables. So do the following: right below the variable declarations create the method `viewDidLoad` if it does not exist (which can only be because you removed it) like the following: `override func viewDidLoad() {/*In here, paste everything from your if statement except the line that starts with func ...*/}

Comment: I wonder how your code even compiles and runs. Now next: paste the `func pressed()` **after** the closing brace for the `viewDidLoad`. Then everything should be fine and work.

Comment: I can't put it in the viewDidLoad because all the code is presumed off of whether the user lost or not. All this code is in a `@IBAction` function.

Comment: Oh ok because you wrote it is in the class, not a function. You know what? Look at YouTube and study the basics. That doesn't help here.

Comment: Alright, one last try: move the `func pressed()` below the closing brace of the `IBAction`.